# How do i change the value of an input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhjtgras/)

I am having trouble letting a user enter their name into a text box and when they click continue it changes another input value for testing reeaons its a textbox but when I put it in my website when its working the input it will be changing will be a hidden value

current javascript

```
function enterUsername(){
     document.getElementById("ign").value = 'test';
};
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/rhjtgras/1/

Comment: Almost but i need it to put it into a input field so put it into a textbox

Comment: something like this then? http://jsfiddle.net/rhjtgras/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is only in the local scope. Make it global like this:

```
enterUsername = function(){...
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mz6zyzf9/)